# "Scaling of decimal value resulted in data truncation" via ODBC

Tags: oracle, ms-access, oracle11g, odbc

I'm receiving an error of "Scaling of decimal value resulted in data truncation" when simply trying to view an ODBC table in MS Access. I know the field that is returning the error, and Access is able to recognize the field when querying off of it, but I'm not able to view the results (`#Error` records) and the error keeps kicking back.

I've tried `CDbl()` with no luck. A `Nz()` doesn't even allow the query to run.

The source database is Oracle, connected via Database Client 11g Release 2 for Microsoft Windows x64. The field is defined by the data dictionary as `Number` with a length of `22`. Design view shows the fields a `Decimal` with precision of `13`, but a scale of 2.

I'm guessing the scale of `2` is causing this error. I'm linking the table via MS Access. Is there anyway for me to resolve this with access to Access and the ODBC, or does this need to be resolved in Oracle?

Comment: Please edit your question to fill in several missing details like **(1)** What sort of database is the ODBC Linked Table connecting to? **(2)** Which ODBC driver are you using (exact name and version)? **(3)** How is the field defined in the source database (e.g. `decimal(18,0)`)? **(4)** How does that same field appear when you open the Access linked table in Design View?

Comment: Thanks, @GordThompson You led me right to it.

Comment: I read this and then asked my DBA of the SQL database to change all the decimal fields to Precision = 28 numbers and Scale = 6 decimals. This solved the problem (you may need to use different parameters for your data).  You can see the Precision and Scale in the design view of the linked table to check the difference between the number fields.  Note after the DBA changed the underlying fields you will need to 'Refresh Link' to see the changes (right-click option on the linked table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Oracle server recently changed its scale from 2 to 4 to allow the greater precision. Linked MS Access tables do not update when the change is made on the server. The table must be removed and relinked for the scale to refresh.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced this issue some days ago and thanks to DAPOLE I had the solution which I share...

- Whenever dealing with linked tables in Access and you change the underlying table definition - when creating your front-end you MUST relink your linked tables for the changes to propagate to Access.
- In my case I had changed the linked tables data definition to from numeric to numeric(5,2) but hadn't relinked the tables,
- so on entering or calculating decimal values Access didn't know that it could store them,
- hence the error `Error scaling of decimal value resulted in data truncation.`

Answer (score 0):

You can use path though query for show your table as following:

[image]

You can find useful information for creating path through query and how to edit on it here:

[path through query](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-pass-through-query-b775ac23-8a6b-49b2-82e2-6dac62532a42)