# Using PHP & ODBC_RESULT, Why am I losing the 4th decimal place

Tags: php, sql, excel, odbc

I'm hoping this is an easy question.

If I run an ODBC connection via Excel I get exactly what I would expect to see from the database. When I port the query over to Xampp for testing I can not get the query to display the 4th decimal place in the results.

Here is my SQL query defined in Excel:

```
SELECT MC_BOM_DETAIL.finished_item, MC_BOM_DETAIL.item_num, MC_BOM_DETAIL.quantity, MC_BOM_DETAIL.line_num, IC_INVENTRY_MAST.um_stocking
FROM IC_INVENTRY_MAST IC_INVENTRY_MAST, MC_BOM_DETAIL MC_BOM_DETAIL
WHERE IC_INVENTRY_MAST.company = MC_BOM_DETAIL.company AND IC_INVENTRY_MAST.item_num = MC_BOM_DETAIL.item_num
ORDER BY MC_BOM_DETAIL.finished_item, MC_BOM_DETAIL.line_num
```

The php page executing the query is as follows

```
//Define ODBC Connection
$mas_conn  =  odbc_connect("odbc_connection", "user_name", "password");

//Define Query
$query = "SELECT mbd.finished_item, mbd.item_num, mbd.line_num, mbd.quantity, icm.um_stocking
FROM IC_INVENTRY_MAST icm, MC_BOM_DETAIL mbd
WHERE icm.company = mbd.company AND icm.item_num = mbd.item_num
ORDER BY mbd.finished_item, mbd.line_num";

if($result=odbc_exec($mas_conn, $query)) {
     while(odbc_fetch_row($result)){
         echo odbc_result($result,'quantity') .'<br>';
      } 
}
odbc_free_result($result);
odbc_close($mas_conn);
```

The results are always truncated (not rounded) to the 3rd decimal place, however I need precision to the 4th.

I looked through the php.ini file to see if that maybe the cause but came up short.

Does anybody have an suggestions?

Thank you for your time.

**Solution:**
The issue in my case was with the Data Definitions inside the source data. This is a bit tricky as the database is read only, and the ODBC driver is provided by 3rd party (ProvideX). After speaking with a tech at the software manufacture, I was able to change the data definitions which was set to decimal(8,3). Why Excel could read the 4th decimal and the php odbc connection could not is still unanswered. My only thought would be since Excel is running locally.

Answer (score 0):

Check You Windows Localization Settings:

Panel Control->Region and Language -> Formats -> Additional Settings -> No of digits after decimal...

Comment: Was set to 2, changed to 4 still not fixed.

Comment: Try to use: odbc_setoption for change preccision.

Comment: What is result of odbc_field_len()/ ?

Comment: Thank you for the response AnR, odbc_field_len($result,'quantity') is 8 so that appears to be long enough for a 4 decimal. I'm going to research the odbc_setoption. I just feel like this has to be related to the PHP part of it not the odbc connection and query as I use the same connection in Excel and PHP.

Comment: odbc_field_type($result,'quantity') is DECIMAL

Comment: Okay I think I found the issue. odbc_field_scale($result,'quantity') = 3. Which is causing the data to get truncated. Similar issue here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23019139/scaling-of-decimal-value-resulted-in-data-truncation-via-odbc/23021694#23021694) Still working on how or if it is possible to redefine the field scale.